# Unresolved external symbol on virtual function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, virtual-functions, unresolved-external

Each of these classes are in separate dll modules:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void foo();
  void bar();
};


class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  // override Base::foo()
  void foo();
};
```

In Other.cpp:

```
#include "Derived.h"
```

The module that contains Derived links with Base.lib (not shown are the export/import directives). The module that contains Other.cpp links with Derived.lib, but not Base.lib. Up to this point, everything works fine.

However, if I change Base::bar() to be virtual and do not make a change to Derived, then the linker complains when linking Other.dll:

```
Other.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Base::bar()" ...
```

The only solutions I have found is to override Base::bar() in Derived or to have Other.dll also link with Base.lib. Both solutions are not desired because they add client requirements when the server changes.

Any ideas on a better way to access/define the base class virtual methods in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that `virtual Base::bar` needs to be in the vtable of a Derived, since there's no `Derived::bar`.

I don't understand your comment about "client requirements when the server changes". I don't see how base/derived maps to client/server. They're two independent dimensions to me.